# throw without arguments inside try/catch block causes the application to crash

Tags: c++, exception

Let's say somewhere in my code I want to throw an exception without argument to just break a function execution due to an error/incorrect behavior.
So the simplified code is:

```cpp
try
{
    std::cout << "before throw" << std::endl;
    throw;
} catch(...)
{
    std::cout << "catch" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "after try/catch" << std::endl;
```

But the output is:

```cpp
before throw
terminate called without an active exception
```

Actually I expected to get

```cpp
before throw
catch
after try/catch
```

Ok, I know that throw without arguments used to rethrow an exception. But according to the standard a handler  with ellipsis should catch any exception. I didn't find any doc that describes such a behavior. This is certainly not a working example, I'm just wondering why this is happening.

Comment: `throw;` - _"...This form is only allowed when an exception is presently being handled (it calls std::terminate if used otherwise)..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw

Comment: But to **rethrow** you need to have an already active exception. You cannot rethrow _nothing_. I would just use a `std::exception` if nothing else is available.

Comment: "But according to the standard a handler with ellipsis should catch any exception" - And what is that exception object exactly if you don't provide one?

Comment: In general, you should only use `throw;` when you're **inside** a `catch` block.

Comment: Re: "throw an exception without argument" -- can't do that. The argument that follows the `throw` **is** the exception that's thrown.

Comment: thanks @RichardCritten for the link, this basically answers my question.